# textLabel.backgroundColor on UITableViewCell does not work

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to set the label backgroundColor of my UITableViewCells and it does absolutely nothing at all. I wonder if there's another way of doing this, so I'm asking!

I tried this:

```
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

And it doesn't work, anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I assume you are trying this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

According to the [UITableViewCell class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Note: If you want to change the
>   background color of a cell (by setting
>   the background color of a cell via the
>   backgroundColor property declared by
>   UIView) you must do it in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
>   method of the delegate and not in
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of
>   the data source.

So do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //must do here in willDisplayCell
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //must do here in willDisplayCell
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; //can do here OR in cellForRowAtIndexPath
}
```

If you need finer control over the cell display, an easy way is to design it in IB and load it from the nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  See the "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files" section on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) in the Table View Programming Guide.

Comment: Awesome, was looking everywhere for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update for IOS 9.3.  This actually works fine in cellForRowAtIndexPath using IOS 9.3.  Also Note: To change the color of the entire cell use:

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];