# Can't set UITableView cell label background color and text alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Setup row background image (a.k.a the set image)
    NSString *setID = [[self.wallpaperCollectionArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *setImageName = [@"s-" stringByAppendingString:setID];
    UIImage *setImage = [UIImage imageNamed:setImageName];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:setImage];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:setImage];

    NSString *setName = [[self.wallpaperCollectionArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [setName uppercaseString];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:20];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    // Not working?
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;   // Not working?

    return cell;
}
```

Nevertheless, the result is rather weird, where the `backgroundColor` and `textAlignment` do not get applied.

[image: meh!]

This is a programmatically created UITableView. What should I do?

**UPDATE:** the background color issue is solved. Still stumped with the centering.

Comment: what is your deployment target?

Comment: I believe [this post is the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164459/changing-uitableviewcell-textlabel-background-color-to-clear) and will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610547/textlabel-backgroundcolor-on-uitableviewcell-does-not-work

Comment: @Virussmca iOS 6 upwards.

Comment: @Patt That works. Any idea what to do with the centering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for the centering issue by changing `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` in

```
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

NSTextAlignment does not work for styles UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and  UITableViewCellStyleDefault .

So if  you need to align the textLabel in your cell use  UITableViewCellStyleValue2 .

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (and doing so cuts off the text on the table cells, too: "BOLD...", "DREAM...", and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion : Instead of doing this alignment programatically , I would suggest you to create a custom cell with nib file containing background image and all other controls as per your requirements. This will help you in future if you need to change the UI . In xib file , you can directly set text alignment also .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

**First set the frame for cell**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    [super layoutSubviews]

    textLabelFrame.size.width=250.0f;
    self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
}
```

Then i think it will work for center Alignment.

**Let me know if you have any problem.**

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Where do I put this method?

Comment: @hfz you put it in a UITableViewCell subclass and return that subclass instead from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding your own `UILabel` as a subview and using only it and never `cell.textLabel`. That way you have complete control (without any interference) over text alignment and view frame.

Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        /* 
         * Make the label cover the entire bounds of the cell, no matter how the cell resizes
         * (Old school autoresizing still works because it gets translated into constraints)
         */
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        /*
         * No need to set this stuff repeatedly, let's just do it
         * once on creation of the label
         */
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:20];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    // Should work now
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;   // Should work now

        // Set a tag so we can find this label later
        label.tag = 42;
    }

    // Setup row background image (a.k.a the set image)
    NSString *setID = [[self.wallpaperCollectionArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *setImageName = [@"s-" stringByAppendingString:setID];
    UIImage *setImage = [UIImage imageNamed:setImageName];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:setImage];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:setImage];

    NSString *setName = [[self.wallpaperCollectionArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];

    // Find our custom UILabel and configure it
    UILabel *label = (id)[self.contentView viewWithTag:42];
    label.text = [setName uppercaseString];

    return cell;
}
```

Even better, use a UITableViewCell subclass instead. It makes your code more organized. In that case you could use @user1673099's suggestion.